# What does 日曜日ぐらい mean in the following sentence?

Tags: particle-くらい

> 日曜日ぐらいは家族とともに過ごしたい。

I have looked it up 2 dictionaries and a number of JLPT grammar exercise books but have not figured out what usage of ぐらい this is. Could somebody help and explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiktionary [says](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84#Adverb) that there exists a meaning of "at least", and their example seems to match yours:

> 今回{こんかい}くらいは頑張{がんば}ろうかな。- Maybe I should put in the effort at least once (this time).

See @naruto's comment - 日曜日ぐらい here would be "at least on Sundays".

And this is the translations that [deepl gives](https://www.deepl.com/translator#ja/en/%E6%97%A5%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF%E5%AE%B6%E6%97%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB%E9%81%8E%E3%81%94%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%80%82) for what it's worth - "I want to spend at least one Sunday with my family."  although it's not clear where the "one" comes from.

Disclaimer: I don't suggest using DeepL (google translate even less so for Japanese) as a reference but it can be used to get a general direction.

Comment: DeepL is good but it often makes mistakes like any other machine translators. This 日曜日ぐらい means "at least Sundays", not one particular Sunday.

Comment: That's why I added "for what it's worth" - I would never use it as a reference, but it's good to get a general direction. Perhaps it saw too many instances of 今回くらい or similar in the training.

Comment: And surprisingly for Japanese it is better than google translate as far as I can judge